# How to enforce HTTPS access on AVM FRITZ!Box 7412?

Tags: fritzbox

According to [the AVM knowledge database](https://en.avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7490/knowledge-base/publication/show/1525_Importing-your-own-certificate-to-the-FRITZ-Box/) one can configure his_her own certificate for use with FRITZ!OS, but how can I enforce access through HTTPS, i.e. redirection from the HTTP login form to the HTTPS address?

I'm using FRITZ!OS 06.50.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean in the last part of your question. Can you explain a little?

Comment: If I use `http://[ip]` instead of `https://[ip]` to access the Fritz!Box administration page because I typed the address, restored a backup with old browser bookmarks or am following a link online, HTTPS isn't used when it could. I'd like to avoid this behaviour and force myself to always use HTTPS and think about it any more. It's a minor, but legitimate issue.